# Upload multifiles in a server

Tags: php

i want to put a form in my site to upload multifiles in a directory .
 i want a dynamic folder renamed with a date of upload .
can someone help me with a PHP example ?

[image]

Comment: What is a "multifile"? And what is a "dynamic folder"?

Comment: Apart from that: please read about how to ask questions here. Note that SO is _not_ a free coding service. So either you hire a programmer for this, or you start yourself, read and code, and _then_, if you run into a problem with _your code_ that you really cannot solve yourself, _then_ is the time to come here and ask by posting the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

To create dynamic folder:

$folderName = "c://wamp/www/yourprojectpath/".time(); // your folder path will come here

```
            if(! is_dir($folderName) ) {
                mkdir($folderName, 0777);
                chmod($folderName, 0777);
            }
```